# Any API is available for creating in-app product creation in ios app using php or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, in-app-purchase, phonegap-build

I have implemeted in-app purchase in my app. But the problem is app is having so many products in that. My users have privilege to add products at their own price. If i am defining it with tier 1, tier 2 manually. it will not affect all products. I am planing to make the inapp product using some API if available, while the users are adding the product to through my app.
Any API is available for creating in-app product creation in ios app using php or javascript?
Any help?

Comment: If I understand you plan to allow user to create new In App Purchase in ItunesConnect? Or via an API?

I'm sure that is not possible via API and allow user to access to ItunesConnect will require a high privilige level and app-revalidation each time (7days)...

Comment: Thanks for the help. But in my app many products are there. Which can be any number. Users are creating new products in app. How i can implement in app purchase in this case. And they may define price as 1.5$ or 8.34$ like that. Can you help me how to sort out this.